# bootstrap row not working but button working with react js . why?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

[image]i am using bootstrap with react js  my button is working but row is not . why ?

```
<div className="container">
    <div className="row">
       <div className="col-md-6">
            1 of 2
               <button className="btn btn-info">fddfgdf</button>
       </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
            2 of 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the error you get? How do you know it doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

just include the css in your main app as below

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

Comment: @ShahinHasan Your comment is not constructive and rather rude. Why do you believe the answer is bad?

Comment: well a basic question must have "rubbish" answers ;) 
anyhow  i was trying to help ,  it is obviously that the bootstrap css isn't loaded otherwise it would worked

Comment: it sure that i import the css !! that why ?  foolish answer.

Comment: @ShahinHasan Well, you didn't show it. Be polite, please. Why should we enjoy helping users who show that attitude?

Comment: if you see the pic , u can understand... thats why ? people just wants points .

Comment: @ShahinHasan make sure to include that the other time  and talk with some repect the next time make sure to include it check the css on the dev tools to make sure it is loaded and i recommend that you remove any css you have added and check bootstrap version to make sure you are using the correct syntax for the css

Comment: @ShahinHasan Since I feel like it, here you go. A template of how to react maturely. "Thanks for your answer, Fadi. However, I am pretty sure I included the css because [...]. I'll edit my question to make that more clear." You're welcome.

Comment: @ShahinHasan the idea of helping other is the one that motivates people and not the points in the end everybody behavior reflects their mentality

Comment: @ShahinHasan Even if I could, I would not help you with that attitude. Learn to be nice and to apologize, and that is well-meant advice.